# minimal c++ callback on an embedded system with parameters

Tags: c++, function, callback, embedded

I am developing in c++ on an embedded system. Due to ressource constraints i am not allowed to use `std::function` for my callbacks.

I want to register a Callback from an upper layer of the Software, and execute it inside a very low level driver. The thing is this callback also needs to pass parameters as an array and I want to avoid a global variable.

low_level_driver:

```
using callback = void (*)(uint32_t data[2]);

// extern C because it is executed inside an c style interrupt, don't ask
extern "C" {
static callback global_cb = nullptr;

void ExecuteCallback(uint32_t data[2]) {
    if (global_cb != nullptr) {
        global_cb(data);
    }
}

void Interrupt() {
 // Error occured
    uint32_t logData[2] = { 0, 1}; // Dummy data for stackoverflow
    ExecuteCallback(logData);
} 
}

void low_level_driver::RegisterCallback(callback cb) {
    global_cb = cb;
}
```

The Application Layer looks like that:

```
#include "low_level_driver.h"

ResetHandler::ResetHandler() {
    low_level_driver.RegisterCallback(MyCallback);
}

void ResetHandler::MyCallback(uint32_t logData[2]) {
  // log the Data
}
```

Currently i am failing to register my callback in any way possible. I know either my callback is wrong, or how i try to register it inside the application layer is wrong. Need help.

EDIT:
Regardless of how bad this design might be. I am looking for the following:
Basically just a method to have a callback with parameters.

Comment: `void (*)(uint32_t data[2]);` isn't a member function pointer. You could try passing lambda ( that doesn't capture anything) or free function, or even making `MyCallback` `static`.

Comment: ok. i kinda thought it might be a problem. how would i pass this as a lambda? How does it look as a free function.?

Comment: A free function would just be `void MyCallback(uint32_t logData[2]) {
  // log the Data
}` you can also declare it in your header if you like so long as it's not in scope if any class or struct. A lambda might look like `low_level_driver.RegisterCallback([] (uint32_t logData[2]) -> void { // log the Data });`.

Comment: What exactly does the low level driver do? Does it even make sense to use member functions, given that most such drivers are "singletons" - you can only have one ISR and it is to be regarded as `static`. Therefore you can also only have one callback and it should be static too. This is very straight-forward to write in pure C.

Comment: It is a memory protection unit and i want to log away the area, where a violation occured. The stack is already a paraemeter given to the ISR so that it can internally handle a testcase. And the whole architecture around it makes it sometimes more complex than necessary.

Comment: So the stack mentioned here isn't the actual CPU stack but some custom data type, yeah? Or do you have multiple CPU stacks like a RTOS?

Comment: No it is the actual CPU Stack but for my question that is just unnecessary. I just want to pass parameters while executing my callback.

Comment: Umm... so you have a stack overflow, then you trigger an interrupt, which stacks even more stuff on the overflowed stack. And then you pile on local variables on top of that. Then call an additional function, to stack even more stuff. How does any of that make sense?

Comment: Ok a Stack overflow occurs, because an array goes out of bounds somehow. And something trys to write into a protected memory region. So i interrupt the command which would be executed while trying to overwrite a protected region. Which the mpu of the stm32 just does. The interrupt gets as a parameter the current stack address, so it can log where the error occured, or identify if i just did a selftest of the mpu. Now i want to log the data somehow.

Comment: If the stack has gone haywire, there is no way to resolve it in software. You _can't_ even write such code in assembler, because you won't be able to stack registers.

Comment: @Lundin It is just as straightforward in C++, static (member function or free). You may get warnings about different linkage, for a free function, extern "C" will fix that.  In my case the warnings for member functions come only from my standalone static analysis tool, not the compiler.  The code is already necessarily target specific system level code, so the warning is perhaps an irellevant portability issue.

Comment: @d3rdon Think. The SP points at a protected region. ISR happens. The CPU stacks calling parameters for the ISR. Except that never happens, because (hopefully) the CPU can't write to the protected region. Then it tries to allocate 2x32 bit variables, either on the stack, or in registers, if the calling convention tried to push registers on the stack. In either case the variables won't get allocated. Then you call a function, function call overhead getting stacked. Except by now the SP is even deeper into lala land. Then the function returns. Return address is some garbage from protected memory.

Comment: @d3rdon No, the next thing after getting an interrupt for accessing protected memory, will be an interrupt for accessing protected memory. You are stuck in a loop with this design and only the watchdog can save the day.

Comment: yeah. might be true. at least the watchdog is already runnign. are where edge case there it is not the stack that goes haywire, but just bad programing? i think in those cases it might be possible to use it.

Comment: Yes in the general case you can attempt to log the error and then do a MCU reset. But realistically, that log won't be of much help, since you need to know which code that wrote to the wrong address. If you can grab the return address pushed on the stack by the ISR, then save that to the log, the code would get a purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There are alternatives to std::function which neither type erase nor allocate.

My personal favorite is the [delegate implementation](https://github.com/includeos/IncludeOS/blob/master/api/util/delegate.hpp) of [IncludeOS](https://github.com/includeos/IncludeOS). It has two additional template parameters after the function signature which allow customization of the callback size and some optional optimizations based on if it's pure (basically a free function), trivially copyable or neither. The drawback of those additional parameters is that it might bloat your code if you use a lot of different variants of it.

Another alternative might be what MBed does. They have a class called [CThunk](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.9/mbed-os-api-doxy/class_c_thunk.html) which even states in its description that it's purpose is to redirect callbacks to non-static member functions. I haven't used it yet and the API seems way less modern and fancy, but it might fit your needs.

Comment: But you simply can't call all this bloatware from a low level ISR.

Comment: But MBed handles all drivers for you, right? So an application running on top of that sits at such a high level that it will never even have heard of the term ISR.

Comment: ARM specifically mentions that CThunk is (and I directly quote here) "ideally suited for class object receiving interrupts (NVIC_SetVector)".

Answer (score 0):

Callback should be static, try to make **MyCallback** to be static.